# Creating default object from empty value through an array

Tags: php, vbulletin

I have read multiple threads here about the matter, although none of the solutions seem to be similar to mine.  I would have attempted to fix this myself but unable to find anything similar I don't even know where to begin.  Why am I getting this error, and what are the proper steps to resolve it?

```
function handleRequestsave_details()
    {
        $this->vbulletin->input->clean_array_gpc('p', array('fullname' => TYPE_STR,
            'address_1' => TYPE_STR, 'address_2' => TYPE_STR, 'address_city' => TYPE_STR,
            'address_state' => TYPE_STR, 'address_zip' => TYPE_STR, 'country' => TYPE_STR,
            'phone' => TYPE_STR, 'company' => TYPE_STR));
        if ($this->checkDetailsFields('details', $this->vbphrase['memarea_required_fields']))
        {
            $information = $this->buildInfoArray();
            $this->vbulletin->userinfo['ma_info'] = $information;
            $this->vbulletin->userinfo['usergroupid'] = $usergrpid;
            if ($this->setCustomerNumber($information, $usergrpid))
            {
                $vbulletin->url = 'members.php?' . $vbulletin->session->vars['sessionurl'] . "do=details";
                eval(print_standard_redirect('memarea_saved_details', true, true));
            }
        }
    }
```

Here are the other functions included in this script, This is not my code it is simply an old product for vBulletin 3.x I am trying to update for my site.  this portion throwing the error is when customers enter their billing details to save in their profile.

```
 function checkDetailsFields($requested, $errormessage)
    {
        if (empty($this->vbulletin->GPC['fullname']) or empty($this->vbulletin->GPC['address_1']) or
            empty($this->vbulletin->GPC['address_city']) or empty($this->vbulletin->GPC['address_zip']) or
            empty($this->vbulletin->GPC['country']) or empty($this->vbulletin->GPC['phone']))
        {
            //$GLOBALS['error'] = $errormessage;
            eval(standard_error($errormessage));
            //$this->handleRequest($requested);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

function buildInfoArray()
    {
        return array('fullname' => $this->vbulletin->GPC['fullname'], 'address_1' => $this->
            vbulletin->GPC['address_1'], 'address_2' => $this->vbulletin->GPC['address_2'],
            'address_city' => $this->vbulletin->GPC['address_city'], 'address_state' => $this->
            vbulletin->GPC['address_state'], 'address_zip' => $this->vbulletin->GPC['address_zip'],
            'country' => $this->vbulletin->GPC['country'], 'phone' => $this->vbulletin->GPC['phone'],
            'company' => $this->vbulletin->GPC['company']);
    }

function setCustomerNumber($ma_info, $usergroup = '', $usevb = true, $userinfo = '')
    {
        if ($usevb == false)
        {
            $this->vbulletin->userinfo = &$userinfo;
        }
        $fcust = $this->fields['custnum'];
        $fpass = $this->fields['mpassword'];
        $finfo = $this->fields['info'];
        $userdm = datamanager_init('User', $this->vbulletin, ERRTYPE_ARRAY);
        $userinfo = fetch_userinfo($this->vbulletin->userinfo['userid']);
        $userdm->set_existing($userinfo);
        if (!$this->vbulletin->userinfo["$fcust"] and !$this->vbulletin->userinfo["$fpass"])
        {
            $rand = rand($this->vbulletin->options['memarea_numstart'], $this->vbulletin->
                options['memarea_numend']);
            $num = $this->vbulletin->options['custnum_prefix'] . substr(md5($rand), 0, $this->
                vbulletin->options['memarea_custnumleng'] - strlen($this->vbulletin->options['custnum_prefix']));
            $userdm->set($fcust, $num);
            $pass = substr(md5(time() . $num . $rand . rand(0, 2000)), 0, $this->vbulletin->
                options['memarea_custnumleng']);
            $userdm->set($fpass, $pass);
            $this->sendCustomerInfo($this->vbulletin->userinfo['userid'], $this->vbulletin->
                userinfo['username'], $this->vbulletin->userinfo['email'], $num, $pass);
        }
        if ($usergroup or $usergroup !== '' or $usergroup !== '0')
        {
            if ($usergroup != $this->vbulletin->userinfo['usergroupid'])
            {
            $ma_info['oldgroup'] = $this->vbulletin->userinfo['usergroupid'];
            $userdm->set('usergroupid', $usergroup);
            }
        }
        if ($ma_info)
        {
            $ma_info = serialize($ma_info);
            $userdm->set($finfo, $ma_info);
        }

        $userdm->pre_save();
        if (count($userdm->errors) == 0)
        {
            $userdm->save();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            var_dump($userdm->errors);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The use of $this suggests your function is part of a class.

Comment: There are a lot of function calls to source code we don't have and data which we don't know what it would contain or how it's set up.  Also add to that the call to `eval()` on something we can't tell what it does makes it hard to help (IMHO).

Comment: Added the additional functions, and a statement.  If anyone could help me to do this in a better manner that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As for the call to the eval that is standard vBulletin messages for page redirection.